# Install Fortran 90 compiler in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, fortran

I am trying to run a package that strictly depends on Fortran 90, but after running its `./configure` file it shows the following error:

```
configure: error: could not find Fortran 90 compiler
```

There are multiple [sources for compiling](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers) Fortran 95, but not for 90.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortran 95 is a superset of Fortran 90. A Fortran 95 compiler will quite likely be able to compile your Fortran 90 code.

To install the GNU Fortran compiler from kubuntu use:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```

In fact, the Fortran 95 standard was just a minor upgrade from the Fortran 90 standard (unlike the change from Fortran 77 to Fortran 90).

Comment: It looks like I had to reboot the machine in order to get rid of that error. Anyways, It is useful to know that it is contained by f95, I didn't found that very explicitly.

Comment: AFAIK, even a `f90` compiler would switch to `f77` mode when compiling a Fortran 77 source file.

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar That does not make sense. Reboot the machine? Really?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes. Strange.